# Configuring HSRP on Nexus OS

Tags: cisco-ios-12, cisco-nx-os, cisco-nexus-7k, hsrp

How do you configure HSRP on a Nexus 7000 series switch?

I know in IOS the commands are in the interface configuration, for example:

```
switch-a#config t
switch-a(config)#interface g1/0/1
switch-a(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
switch-a(config-if)#standby 10 ip 10.1.1.1
switch-a(config-if)#standby 10 priority 110
switch-a(config-if)#standby 10 preempt
```

When I am configuring an interface in Nexus OS, the standby command isn't there.  My output of "?-ing" around in the interface config mode doesn't give anything that looks likely...  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a Cisco Nexus switch, the syntax for HSRP is actually "HSRP" instead of "Standby".

In my experience, it makes it easier to troubleshoot as you know immediately which redundancy protocol you're dealing with (HSRP, GLBP, or VRRP).

See [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9402/products_configuration_example09186a0080b7e104.shtml) Cisco doc for more information on HSRP on the Nexus 7000 platform.

---

First, be sure that you have enabled HSRP on the device:

```
switch-b(config)#feature hsrp
```

Then go into the interface and issue the command "hsrp *groupnumber*".   You will then be able to enter your configuration similarly to in IOS.  This actually takes you into a sub-configuration mode as shown below:

```
switch-b(config)#interface Eth1/1 
switch-b(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.3/24
switch-b(config-if)#hsrp 10
switch-b(config-if-hsrp)#preempt
switch-b(config-if-hsrp)#priority 90
switch-b(config-if-hsrp)#ip 10.1.1.1
```

Don't forget to "no shut" the interface, but then that should do it!

---

Also, I just realized that Cisco has a great writeup on these differences [here](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Cisco_NX-OS/IOS_HSRP_Comparison) on their DocWiki.